# Microsoft Access Macro - is there a way to copy records with a macro?

Tags: microsoft-word, macros, microsoft-access

I have written a macro in Microst Access that runs a make-table query, opens the table and selects all the records.  (I don't know VBA so I have to use macros).

Then I copy all the records and paste them into Word and run a macro I've created there.

Is there a way to add a command of some sort to copy selected records?

If so, here would be the end result that I'm trying to accomplish.

By adding this to a menu item, the End User would simply click the Run Whatever Report button and it would go through all these steps:

1. Run a make-table query.
2. Open the resulting table.
3. Select all records and fields.
4. Copy all selection.
5. Open Word.
6. End User clicks previously created macro button.
7. Task completed.

My End Users are at the very basic level and are menu-button driven.  If they have to manually select the records, I will (seriously) have to write a manual on "How To". Therefore the reason for my desired end result.

Thanks for any help or suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=376693 (interesting info that may be close to what you are looking for).

If you must use a macro, [this site](http://www.databasedev.co.uk/export-macro.html) looked promising.

Comment: Could you expand your answer? Its a bit unclear exactly what your suggesting to do.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I really do need to delve into the world of VBA.  Time seems to be the biggest factor for me.  What I know about Access I've had to teach myself through trial and error (no classes, no books...sigh).  My biggest problem on this one is the deadline and I don't have time to learn VBA in time to meet the deadline. :-(  Thanks for the links! Will definitely look into them and hopefully be able to put them to use!

Answer (score 0):

Why not just create a report using the Access Report Designer?  It's not that hard and doesn't require knowing VBA.  There are report wizards for basic designs.  You already have your "make table" query that creates the data to be reported.  Just choose it in the report wizard and in a few simple steps you will have a basic report.  Once the report is designed and saved you can create a simple one-step macro to open that report and put that macro on a menu button.

You can then use the Office Links button on the toolbar to export the report to Word, if that's still necessary.

If you want to learn more about creating reports starting with using the wizard, here's a very clear video tutorial on YouTube: http://bit.ly/xQBzjp

Comment: I can create a report but my end user needs this in MS Word format. Basically, they need a text version of my FN and LN field to go from being columns to end up like this in Word: John Doe*Jim Rupert*Leslie Lester*Mandy Manilow     I have solved this problem, but thanks for the suggestion!